# a precise "description" of $\lim s_n > \lim t_n$

Tags: real-analysis

The motivation came from trying to prove $s_n > t_n$ $\forall n > 1 \implies \lim s_n \ge \lim t_n$ directly. (I know about the contradiction approach.) But I found it a little difficult to find a direct proof since I can't make $\lim s_n > \lim t_n$ precise.

Take two sequences $\lim s_n > \lim t_n$ in a metric space $X$.

When asked to show that $\lim s_n > \lim t_n$, what precisely is being asked here? I'm looking for something more in line with the precise definition of the limit of a sequence.

I came up with this. $\lim s_n = s > \lim t_n = t \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ s.t. $s_n > t_n$ and $d(s, s_n) < \epsilon$ and $d(t, t_n) < \epsilon$. Since I know both $s_n$ and $t_n$ are convergent, all I have to show is that $s_n > t_n$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the main question maybe it would help you to think in $a=\lim a_n>0$  and what does it mean in sequence? It is not difficult to show that this means that the sequence is eventually bounded away from zero [ there is some positive value $c$ such that all the terms greater than $N$ (in index) are at least  this $c$, i.e., $a_n\ge c>0$ for all $n\ge N$]. In your case $s=\lim s_n>t=\lim t_n$, so $\,s-t= \lim (s_n-t_n)>0$. Then there is some $c>0$ and  $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $s_n-t_n\ge c>0$, then $s_n>t_n$.

On the other hand for a easy proof of the statement:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then there is a sufficient large $N$ such that $|s_n-s|\le \varepsilon$ and $|t_n-t|\le \varepsilon$ at the same time. Thus, $$t-\varepsilon\le t_n<s_n\le s+\varepsilon  $$

So, $t<s+2\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary then $t\le s$ [otherwise we can set $\varepsilon=(t-s)/2$ and reached a contradiction].

Answer (score 1):

Note $x>y$ iff there exists $z$ such that $x>z>y$. Suppose then $s=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n>\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  t_n=t$. Pick $r$ such that $s>r>t$.

1. Since $s_n\to s$, there exists for $\varepsilon_0 =\dfrac{s-r}2$ an $N_{\varepsilon_0}$ such that...
2. Since $t_n\to t$, there exists for $\varepsilon_1=\dfrac{r-t}2$ an $N_{\varepsilon_1}$ such that...

I'll let you finish.

Comment: it sounds like we are starting with the conclusion $s>t$?

Comment: Yes. If for some $N>0$; we have $t_n\geqslant r'>r>r''\geqslant s_n$ for each $n\geqslant N$, we clearly have $t>r>s$, so I am trying for you to go the other way.